# is it neccesary to use nginx or apache for python web in production?

Tags: nginx, apache2, fastapi, hypercorn, ariadne-graphql

I am developing a graphql api using ariadne and fastapi and thinking of launching it on hypercorn server. I don't have to serve static files and images. So, In my case is it necessary to use nginx or apache2 with hypercorn while I am going in production.

Note:- There will be a heavy traffic on this server

If it is necessary to use apache2/nginx , how can I configure to use it with hypercorn ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Historically apache2/nginx was recommended in front of Python servers as the Python servers could only serve a single request at a time, and apache2/nginx could buffer the requests. See for example [Gunicorn's docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html). This isn't the case for Hypercorn (and Gunicorn's async workers) so apache2/nginx is not required.